# Screen turns black for a few secs while watching full screen video

Tags: windows-8.1, video, graphics-card

After I have changed my video card to `MSI N770 TF 2GD5/OC, nVidia GeForce, GTX770` is started to blink (turn black for a few seconds) while watching full screen video (with MPC-HC).

The blackouts occur random, but very often tends to occur at the same place of a video. I.e. if rewind then it will appear at the same place in 90% cases (not 100%). These blackouts are not embedded into video, because they do not occur in windowed playback and not occur in 100% in the same place.

Also these blackouts occur while playing fullscreen video games.

Looks like videocard turns of for a few seconds if some video event happen.

No any error messages or log entries appear.

What can it be?

**UPDATE**

I don't have any overheating, reported by monitoring software.

I don't overclock yet.

My driver is 340.52, which is latest.

My power is 650 W. I can't imagine, how can power problems manifest at specific places of video. I can rewind back a second and have blackout exactly at the same place for dozens of times.

The same blackout occur both in MPC-HC and VLC Player. Playing with rendering options didn't fix the problem.

**UPDATE 2**

Updating firmware for motherboard ETC didn't help.

**UPDATE 3**

Also I noticed, that narrow blue horizontal lines are blinking from time to time at the right side of the screen (while watching full screen). This is somehow reminding old-era ELT television screens...

Comment: could be a GPU recover you could increase the cooling manually and see if it still occurs. Switch MPC to a non-3d renderer and see if it still does it?  In testing here there is not a whole lot of difference in some of the older render methods in picture quality filtering and all, and it does not take much more CPU , so in view->options->output switch to a overlay mixer (lowest) or a vmr9, and on the right make sure the 3d stuff is off, and still make sure to apply a resizer like bicubic 1.0. So it is no sweat to test that.  GPU recovers can occur when the processor itself is cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry people, it was just a problem with `HDMI` cable connection. Never thought bad cable connection can cause such specific glitches as it was...

Comment: When I surf the web, if I load a webpage that has a video on it (only about 0.5% of videos, roughly.) - my entire screen goes black for 2-3 seconds.

My rig:

* Nvidia GTX 970
* HannsG HZ281
* HDMI to HDMI cable
* Windows 8
* Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m

This problem has persisted for me for years. I believe the same problem happened when I used to have a GTX 560 Ti. I think the HDMI cable is the same though.

I will buy a new HDMI cable and report back! Thanks for your published solution.

Comment: Just bought a new HDMI to HDMI v1.4 cable, which replaced my old DVI to HDMI cable.. and the same issue remains. Loading this URL https://vimeo.com/153228888 consistently makes my screen go black for 2 secs shortly after the page loads, and again when I exit it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Had the same issue with a Hama cable for which I've paid a lot of money (Gold or something). Replaced it with an unnamed cable and works great now.

Answer (score 2):

update your drivers and also check if your PC is having an adequate power supply to power your graphics card. If you overclock, make sure you don't mess with the PCI-E bus frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Check your windows power settings? Switch it to Max/High performance and see if that fixes the issue.
If it doesn't, try taking the video card out of the motherboard, use a can of air to blow out the cartridge slot it was in, and reseat it firmly. It sounds like a loss of connection or power, but only momentarily.

Also, try downloading a linux live CD such as Ubuntu or Fedora; and running glxtest or some videos in full screen there and see if it also blacks out. That will either confirm or rule out a driver/os issue.