# My screen goes black when watching a video

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5

I've been having this issues for a lot of months. 
As I tried to tackle this issues, it hasn't worked out yet. Which is a shame, because it's really annoying. Now I tried googling around, but I found this topic on this site:
[Black screen issue playing videos in YouTube on Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/723402/black-screen-issue-playing-videos-in-youtube-on-google-chrome) I tried it, which didn't work. Although all pages with HTML5 basically crash.

Any solutions? I'm running Google Chrome.

Also my whole screen goes black, for like 3 seconds. Sometimes it happens when my screen is black for a long time, which I fix with using my second monitor and closing Chrome. My second monitor doesn't go black.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware compatibility problem.  You have the require device drivers installed?

Comment: @Ramhound graphics card drivers are updated

Comment: Dupe @ http://superuser.com/questions/807488/#827237